# Change text content of pre-set drop down list in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, list

I have the following HMTL, which includes a drop down list with pre-set content coming from a locked down CMS (BigCommerce).

I am trying to change the text in the first value of the drop down list, but without success. The HTML is:

```
<select name="return_action" id="return_action" class="Field350">
    <option value="">-- Please Choose an Action (Optional) --</option>
    <option value="Repair">Repair</option>
    <option value="Replacement">Replacement</option>
    <option value="Store Credit">Store Credit</option>
</select>
```

I want to change the innerHTML of the first option as below:

```
<option value="">-- Please Choose an Action (Optional) --</option>
```

Some of the code I have tried without success (ie: the text was changed but the rest of the options in the list were erased in the process):

```
$('#return_action').html('<option value="">-- Please Choose an Action --</option>');

$('#return_action').val(0).html('<option value="">-- Please Choose an Action --</option>');

$('#return_action').val(1).html('<option value="">-- Please Choose an Action --</option>');
```

Essentially I am trying to remove the "(optional)" text from the default selection message.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MU8ap/

`$('#return_action option[value=""]').html('new value');`

`$('#return_action option[value=""]')` selects the right option. As soon as you've selected it, you are free to change it. In this case I replace the inner body of the option-tag throght the .html method with a new text.

Comment: CHAMPION!!! Thank you very much for the help (and sanity rescue!). Worked a treat!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#return_action").val($("#return_action option:first").val());
```

Comment: Hi Tdeland, thank you for the suggestion, but it had no effect on the text. The page loads and the text remains unchanged. Thanks all the same for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ekZ2/1/

```
$(function () {  $('#return_action').children('option:first').text('-- Please Choose an Action  --');
});
```

This will change the first option of the select list.

Comment: CHAMPION!!! Thank you very much for the help (and sanity rescue!). Worked a treat too!!